# How does reflection polarise light on the atomic level?

Tags: electromagnetism, reflection, polarization, absorption

From my reading when light is reflected S-p polarisation occurs with the reflected light being parallel to the surface in polarisation and the mixed light being transmitted through. Light is absorbed, transmitted and is reflected. In the case of a polariser it seems to me the geometric makeup allows for the reflected light on the edges of its grid to transmit through thus in this special case the “transmitted” light is the one polarised as it is made up of edges and is in fact being reflected off of them? Is S-p polarisation an allusion S p orbitals? Why does reflection polarise light?

Comment: s and p modes of polarisation are different (one is the plane, the other perpendicular to, the incident surface). s and p atomic orbitals are not an allusion to polarisation. They are just labels.

Comment: I actually feel everybody is lying and it is to do with S an p orbitals at least to some extent. So the surface is the surface and determines the direction but the amount of polarisation that occurs is obviously to do with S and p orbitals and everybody is lying